# facing ERROR: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2) ruby 3 aruba

Tags: cucumber, aruba, ruby-3, ruby-3.1

after upgrading ruby from 2.7 to 3.0 to 3.1 I am facing fowling issue while running the cucumber test

```
  Given a local mode chef repo with nodes 'one,two,three'                                            # features/step_definitions/chef-repo.rb:2
      Expected `knife client create admin -c config.rb -f admin.pem` to succeed but got non-zero exit status and the following output:
      
      ERROR: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)
      
       (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
      ./features/step_definitions/chef-repo.rb:66:in `create_client'
      ./features/step_definitions/chef-repo.rb:58:in `create_admin'
      ./features/step_definitions/chef-repo.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
      ./features/step_definitions/chef-repo.rb:19:in `each'
      ./features/step_definitions/chef-repo.rb:19:in `/^a local mode chef repo with nodes '(.+?)'(?: with admins '(.+?)')?$/'
      features/clean.feature:11:in `a local mode chef repo with nodes 'one,two,three''
    And I create a vault item 'test/item' containing the JSON '{"foo": "bar"}' encrypted for 'one,two' # features/step_definitions/chef-vault.rb:4
    Then the vault item 'test/item' should be encrypted for 'one,two'                                  # features/step_definitions/chef-vault.rb:48
    And I update the vault item 'test/item' to be encrypted for 'two,three'                            # features/step_definitions/chef-vault.rb:14
    Then the vault item 'test/item' should be encrypted for 'one,two,three'
```

It's failing under Auba SpawnProcess start command. Tried upgrading and downgrading arbua version 'aruba', '~> 2.0' & gem 'aruba', '0.5.4' nothing working can someone please help me with this?

in chef-repo.rb its failing on `run_command_and_stop`

```
def create_client(name, args = nil)
  command = "knife client create #{name} -c config.rb -f #{name}.pem"
  run_command_and_stop(command, fail_on_error: true)
  write_file("#{name}.pem", last_command_started.stdout)
end
```

here if we step in `run_command_and_stop` its fails on `command.start` following code in aruba

```
 def start_command(command)
    259:   aruba.config.run_before_hook(:command, self, command)
    260: 
    261:   in_current_directory do
    262:     command.start
    263:   end
    264: 
 => 265:   stop_signal = command.stop_signal
    266:   aruba.announcer.announce(:stop_signal, command.pid, stop_signal) if stop_signal
    267: 
    268:   aruba.config.run_after_hook(:command, self, command)
    269: end
```

Comment: What's the code involved for that `features/step_definitions/chef-repo.rb:66:in 'create_client'` part? would you mind sharing it?

Comment: @Alter Lagos I have updated the summery with the details you asked